# MKMapView blocks main thread while used in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, grand-central-dispatch

I have a basic `UITableView` that contains 20 cells, one of the cells is a `MKMapView` just dropped in as is without any custom code (not even `setRegion:Animated`), if I open the view at the first time and scroll down the table view (towards the map's cell), there is a noticeable hang happens for the app, and if I use `setRegion:Animated` (without dropping any pin) the hang gets longer. However, this block of the main thread disappears on later attempts to scroll towards the map's cell.

I can't use the `MKSnapShotter` because I want the user to interact with the map so an image won't satisfy the case.

the table view does not make any block on the main thread if the map does not exist.

how to avoid blocking the main thread while showing the map's cell for the first time ?

Comment: You could try to have the cell as an iVar and load it on `viewDidLoad`, then just return the cell at the correct `indexPath`

Comment: how to load the cell from viewDidLoad, I tried cellForRowAtIndexPath method it returns nil

Comment: "load" was not the correct word to use. I meant instantiate.

Comment: write the line of code to instantiate the cell in viewDidLoad

Comment: Are you using a static TableViewCell or are you creating your mapview within cellForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: no I create the mapView in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Have you tried adding the map view from a different thread? using dispatch_async

Comment: if you could post some code it would have been more helpful to debug.

Comment: @SlickRick I tried dispatch_async but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

First make a `tableView` IB outlet if you haven't already done so. Create the cell in view did load using `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mapCellIdentifier")` and store that in an ivar. Then in the data source return the cell when the index path is the one you want so inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do

```
if (indexPath.row == wantedRow) { 
    return mapCell 
}
```

The mapCellIdentifier needs to be set in the cell you created in interface builder for the map. This is assuming you have dynamic cells.